# The cardinality of the set of open subsets and related proofs.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been going around in circles trying to prove this things for the last week, I would really appreciate any ideas on any of the next proofs.

Let C be the linear continuum with no endpoints and D a dense countable subset of C.Let O be the set of all the open subsets of C. Show the next things:

1. A subset of A in C is open iff A is the union of a set of open intervals of a linear continuum and extremities in D.
2. $|O| = 2^{\aleph_0}$
3. Every well ordered strictly increasing family of open sets is countable.
4. For every $\delta < \omega_1 $ there is a strictly increasing family $\langle A_\xi: \xi < \delta \rangle$ of open subsets of C.

I only know that for the second one i should find an embedding into the rationals or something similar, but i can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

These are a handful of questions that have been asked before. Let me provide a few helpful hints:

1. One direction is trivial; for the other direction show that every open set is the union of open intervals, and every open interval is the union of open intervals with endpoints in $D$.
2. Use the fact that if $U$ is open, then $U$ is fully determined by the *countable* set of intervals with endpoints in $D$ which are subsets of $U$.
3. If $\langle A_\xi\mid \xi<\delta\rangle$ is an increasing sequence of open sets, then by the fact from the previous hint, this defines a well-ordered family of subsets of $\Bbb N$ ordered by $\subseteq$ which has order type $\delta$. Therefore $\delta<\omega_1$ (assign $\xi$ to least natural number which appears on the $\xi$-th set for the first time).
4. Since every countable linear order embeds into $\Bbb Q$ (and therefore into $D$), embed $\delta$ into $D$ and use it to construct these open sets.

Comment: (3) isn’t quite right: $(0,2)\supsetneqq(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, but the difference has empty interior.

Comment: @Brian: How about identifying each open set with the set open intervals with endpoints in $D$ which lie within it, then this is a well-ordered subset of $(\mathcal P(\Bbb N),\subseteq)$ which is therefore countable?

Comment: That would work. Another argument is to note that if you had an uncountable sequence, you’d have a non-Lindelöf subspace of a second countable space.

Comment: Ha! It didn't even cross my mind to use that sort of argument. :-)